# When can AssemblyName.Version be null?

Tags: c#, .net-core, reflection

The docs show that [`AssemblyName.Version`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.assemblyname.version?view=net-6.0) is nullable. So this could be null:

```cs
Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Version
```

Under what conditions could `Version` be null? The docs do not say.

Comment: Tracking issue on sdk [repo](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/75228)

Comment: There are multiple ways to get an `AssemblyName`. `GetName()` is only one of them. You can also use `AssemblyName`'s default constructor, or use its `string` constructor with a string that does not contain version information. In either case, the version will be null.

Comment: At least in Visual Studio Windows, I cannot set the Assembly version to empty "". It expects me to provide at least one number which can be "0" too!
I even changed the ".csproj" to set it empty and completely removed the prop but then it defaulted to "1.0.0"!
So I guess it will not be null it falls back to the default version in that case!

Comment: @EtiennedeMartel Thanks. In that case, if I get it as I showed above, can I safely assume it will be non-null?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the comment by @EtiennedeMartel and an [answer](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/75228#issuecomment-1240163422) from the repo:

```cs
var an = new System.Reflection.AssemblyName("MyAssembly");
Console.WriteLine(an.Version is null);                     // true
```

So I don't expect it to be null for the cases above, but it could be null for an `Assembly` created dynamically (i.e. at runtime).

Answer (score 0):

Even though you can make an `AssemblyName` with a `null` version, when using `Assembly.GetName()` to get it, this method will create a new instance of AssemblyName and it will have a version of 0.0.0.0. This includes assemblies created at runtime.